# How to show keyboard but disable user input in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I'm using [RichEditorView](https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView) as editor in my app to allow the user to apply different attributes to the text. I want to show to the keyboard but disable user input after 100 characters.

Here what I have tried so far.

1) Tried to change in JS of the RichEditorView but this doesn't work perfectly. The limit for 100 characters works great but the user is still able to press ENTER multiple time. This library internally uses div to make the editor.

Is there any way to handle this in iOS like If I can disable input somehow after 100 characters in WebView?

Comment: "shouldChangeTextIn" is the method which will help you to set limitations and validations

Comment: This is only available with TextField and TextView Delegate not with WebView. :(